# Let `bash -c` keep on ready on prompt

Tags: bash, command-line

How can we have `bash -c` keep on shell prompt, not exit ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want: `bash -c 'your_commands; bash'`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon That would spawn a child process running `bash`. Anything not inherited by the new `bash` shell would be lost (i.e. unexported variables and functions, as well as aliases etc.)  Depending on the circumstances, the new shell may exit immediately (if the input is redirected from `/dev/null`, for example).

Comment: @Kusalananda that's right. I appreciate your comment :D. Maybe that solution is not very useful here but the OP didn't provide more information or I did not understand well perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get into an interactive mode, but execute some script beforehand. Or execute a script and remain in interactive mode. Then key `--init-file` is for you.

Assuming you have `hello.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello"
export PS1=subshell@
```

Do

```
$ bash --init-file hello.sh
Hello
subshell@
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use `expect` which has been implemented in
many languages. In the original TCL one might use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

# run the shell
spawn -noecho bash

# blindly send the input in. another way would be to "expect" on the
# prompt, but that's more complicated
send -- "echo foo\n"
send -- "echo bar\n"

# turn interaction with the program over to the user
interact
```

The downsides include the `expect` process lingering, the plus sides
include that this (more or less) works with really any program
regardless of whether it supports some sort of initial command list
feature thing.